# Is it possible to bind kendo grid dataItem on cell level

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid. i need to bind data over cell, not on **tr** level.
By default dataItem is assigned on **tr** level. Is there any possibility to bind dataItem over Individual **td**

if i do **grid.dataItem(grid.select()**, i dont get dataItem for the selected cell, i need to find the closest **tr** and get dataItem, that is not what i need.

i.e., if  i do select on a cell, selectable:'cell', i have to get dataItem by
**grid.dataItem(grid.select())**

Answer (score 0):

The approach which you are using is working **only if selection mode is not set to cell**. In your case, you need to do one step in addition - select row.

```
change: function(e){
    var grid = $("#cellSelection").data('kendoGrid');
    var row = this.select().closest("tr");
    var selected = grid.dataItem(row);
    console.log(selected);
},
```

[Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/eliRO)

Comment: i need dataItem on the cell i.e., on **td**. your approach is bascially for data binding of a individual object to **tr**. in my case i need data binding on cell level

Comment: Well, then I don't understand what you need, bacause when you select td you will get closest tr and then get dataitem ... it is what you asked in question.